# Is this Question and Answer good enough?

Tags: discussion

Is this Question and Answer good enough?

Question: What is a "child of God"?

Answer: According to Dr. Donald Fairbairn's book *Grace and Christology in the Early Church*, a child of God means "To be a child of God is to remain a finite, mortal creature by nature but to share by grace in that very fellowship and life that characterize God himself."

Dr. Donald Fairbairn is an academic scholar and professor at Gordon-Conwell Theological Seminary. His expertise is in patristics, historical theology, and Eastern Orthodoxy.

It's concise and precise, and it offers a citation to a credible textbook source!

Broadly speaking, what do we do with academic sources produced by theological seminaries and divinity schools? Are they part of a denomination, or do they deserve their own special category?

I personally like and prefer to use academic sources, because they are typically written in a formal language, by experts who have received training in this stuff. Sometimes, their research sheds light on doctrine. Though, I am aware that sometimes it's not that easy to find exactly which denomination the authors belong to, besides the university or school that sponsors the work.

Comment: You could post it and see what kind of votes you get.